# why iptables rules are impacting ping localhost?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ping, localhost

Below is the iptable firewall rules, that I've in my centos system. At this point of time I was not able to ping localhost. `ping localhost` was failing.

But as soon as I did `iptables -F` to flush the rules, I was able to ping localhost.
Question is WHY?? How this iptables set was impacting the functionality of pinging localhost (127.0.0.1)?

```
root@localhost:~# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:6080
LPASS      udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp spt:68 dpt:67
LPASS      all  --  192.168.122.49       0.0.0.0/0
LPASS      tcp  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:21
LPASS      all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LPASS      tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:21
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpts:8505:8506
LPASS      tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:6000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpts:6001:6100
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:161
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:24
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:8081
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:2222
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LDROP      all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.49       tcp dpt:3389
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.49       0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
LFDROP     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vnet+ --physdev-out vnet+ --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68

Chain LDROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LFDROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain LPASS (6 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

ifconfig shows that interface is UP.

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 65922  bytes 5788036 (5.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 65922  bytes 5788036 (5.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: which public IP do you own/have on your server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because **everything** which goes out of an interface and comes into an interface is parsed via the iptables or the firewall rules.

So when a packet has to go out from an interface to itself be it for ICMP, HTTP, FTP or any other protocol. It will go via the same process as in the case of an external IP. So for example in case of HTTP it will start a TCP connection and will then send an HTTP request to localhost and all communications will happen via the **lo** interface.

Now for example you go ahead and make an **OUTPUT** rule as one below:

```
ACCEPT     ICMP  --  127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1
```

and try to run ICMP, It would still not go through, you will need an input rule also as below to make it work:

```
ACCEPT     ICMP  --  127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1
```

Comment: after executing `iptables -F`, everything was cleared and `iptable -L -n` doesn't show anything. In that case how ping starts? Another question would be how the iptables got into this situation where ping started failing.

Comment: because **iptables -F** will flush the iptables rules, **iptables -L -n** is used to list iptables rules which are right now running(or are applied) and if you have already flushed the rules it will not show them.
Go to **/etc/sysconfig/iptables** and you can edit those rules
run **service iptables restart** to make them show again in **iptables -L**

Comment: The ping started failing because you have an **INPUT** rule

LDROP      all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Which Drops all the traffic for all the protocols if none above it is matched, Another way to help this understand would be to use **tcpdump -i lo** you will see packets going out but will never see them coming in.

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra is correct , as your default policy for OUTPUT chain is ACCEPT , you just need to append a rule to allow icmp jst above drop all ( last rule in INPUT CHAIN )

Comment: I would suggest allowing traffic coming through the `lo` interface, instead of basing it on the IP address. IPv4 loopback actually uses the whole 127/8 block, and in practice e.g.  `dnsmasq` likes to use 127.0.1.1. So, `iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` to accept anything from `lo` as the first rule of the `INPUT` table.